# Concating String with parameter in BIP RTF template

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

In my BIP RTF template i am receiving a string in a parameter(say Clinic) and in the IF condition i have to match the parameter($Clinic) with the XML tag (ssRohClinicFacilityName).

Now problem is, incoming parameter is as a truncated string and for a accurate match we have to append a string with the parameter like below:

```
$Clinic + " Clinic"
```

As reports are being generated from Siebel application so there is a limiation on Siebel side on the number of characters to be sent in the parameters.

To achieve above requirement I tried multiple options but none worked for me yet.

I have tried following so far:

- Tried to do concatenation . This is worked as it is but i am not sure how can i use it in the IF condition with the other existing conditions. When i try following i get error.

  = (xdoxslt:format_date($StartDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)) and (xdoxslt:format_date(ssAssignmentDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)))?>
- I tried using XSLT:Subscrting to truncate the ssRohClinicFacilityName but i needed something like this `xdoxslt:substring(ssRohClinicFacilityName, length(ssRohClinicFacilityName)-7, length(ssRohClinicFacilityName)) = $Clinic)` as I only have to truncate last 07 characters but could not found relevant functions

Here is my existing if condition:

```
<?if:( xdoxslt:format_date(ssAssignmentDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE))>= (xdoxslt:format_date($StartDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE)) and (xdoxslt:format_date(ssAssignmentDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE))<= (xdoxslt:format_date($EndDate, 'yyyy-mm-dd','mm/dd/yyyy', $_XDOLOCALE, $_XDOTIMEZONE))?>
```

My sample [RTF](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4yx6x2digz94i46/ROHSHPSSR_A.rtf?dl=0) and [XML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2ipbu3a0nqj9yju/BIP%20ROH%20SH%20Product%20Sales%20Summary%20Report.xml?dl=0) files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it will be easier for you if you just use wildcards for the comparison.

Refer: https://blogs.oracle.com/xmlpublisher/wildcards

& 
https://www.quackit.com/xml/tutorial/xpath_string_functions.cfm

You could search for

```
starts-with(ssRohClinicFacilityName, $Clinic)
```

--New content---

It can be used with and if function, or even without. Here is what I tried:

[image]

And here are the results.

[image]

```
<?starts-with(ssRohClinicFacilityName, $Clinic)?>
```

With an if condition

```
<?if:starts-with(ssRohClinicFacilityName, $Clinic)?> 
'MATCHED'
<?end if?>
```

I suggest you try testing this part separately, there could be other errors in the if statement which is causing incorrect output.

Comment: Hi, thanks. Please can you tell me how it will fit in the IF condition?

Comment: I just tried putting this condition starts-with(ssRohClinicFacilityName, $Clinic) like this <?if (starts-with(ssRohClinicFacilityName, $Clinic)?> but i can see results that does not starts with $Clinic are also appearing.

Comment: It can be used with and if function, or even without. I have posted screenshots from my testing into answer.